# Prove the series $\sum a_n$ when $a_n=\frac{a(a+d)(a+2d)\dots (a+(n-1)d)}{b(b+d)(b+2d)\dots (b+(n-1)d)}$ is divergent, $a,b,d>0$ and $b-a=d$ and $b>a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Now I have battled with this and a friend told me this series is divergent but I am struggling to prove it. So if we replace all the "b's" with "a+d" then $a_n$ reduces too $\frac{a}{a+nd}$ and by the ratio test, Raabe's Test, Root Test this is inconclusive.

Can anyone offer me a tip or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{a}{a+nd}}{1/n}=\frac ad\ne0,$$
and $\sum\limits_{n}\frac1n$ diverge, we know the series is diverges too.

Answer (score 0):

If we try integral test on $f(x)=a/(a+xd)$ over $[1,t]$ it's 
$$\frac{a \ln([dt+a]/(a+d))}{d},$$
which as $t \to \infty$ goes to $\infty.$

Answer (score 0):

Noting $b=a+d$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
a_n&=&\frac{a(a+d)(a+2d)\dots (a+(n-1)d)}{b(b+d)(b+2d)\dots (b+(n-1)d)}\\
&=&a\frac{a+d}{b}\frac{a+2d}{b+d}\cdots\frac{a+(n-1)d}{b+(n-2)d}\frac{1}{b+(n-1)d}\\
&=&\frac{a}{b+(n-1)d}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence $\sum a_n$ diveges.